# Passing values to a query that may be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a filter section for a website that will return objects from the DB.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE type = "1"
AND age < 50
AND age > 20
```

When entering this query, some users may not want to set a type, just filter it by age? Is there any sort of wild card i can pass into the query so it returns all if it not been defined by the user?

The type can either be 1, 2 or 3. if this is not passed into it, i want it to return all users between the age of 20 and 50, and then all types?

Comment: `where (type is null or (type = "1")) and (age is null or (...`

Comment: then only use age filter remove type filter. SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE 
age  BETWEEN 50
AND  20

Comment: where age between 20 and 50 or type= 2

Answer (score 0):

These could be two possible solutions, first is simple if you want all records when age between 50 and 20. Second query will return records if type=1 and age between 50 and 20,

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 50
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 
    IF(type == 1) 
    THEN 
        type = 1 
    ELSE 
        1=1 
    END IF
AND age BETWEEN 20 AND 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 50 AND COALESCE(TYPE,'1')=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select * from table_name where age between 20 and 50 AND type is null
```